# Using Pushd with credentials?

Tags: windows

I run a for loop on devices that does this:

```
pushd \\someshare && dir | grep "blabla" && popd
```

However, while trying to access an administrative share on another device, since I don't provide credentials, it fails:

```
pushd \\192.168.1.1\IPC$ //error: The network resource type is not correct.
```

I know I can use `net use` with credentials instead, but I specifically need to use `pushd` here.

Is anyone familiar with a away to use it as another user?

Comment: Wait, how does `net use` prevent you from using `pushd` immediately after?

Comment: My goal is to perform the operation in a single line, and to not to mount any drive except for the time of run

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store the username and password for 192.168.1.1 in the credential manager? Or is this somehow not an option?
You could also run it as a different user with runas

`runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\user "cmd.exe /c pushd \\192.168.1.1\IPC$"`

But it will open a new command line window so it might not be useful because of that.

Comment: This is good!! isn't there any way to make it run in the same window?

Comment: Sadly, no. Atleast not by using the runas command this always opens a new window. Maybe there is some third party tool that is similar to sudo in Unix but I personally haven't used any of those tools